quantikz2 problems with faded drop shadows
There seems to be a bug with faded drop shadows in quantikz2.
I've been using quantikz (1.x) with TexLive 2020, where I gave my circuit diagrams nice looking drop shadows by attaching this style:
\tikzset{
  operator/.append style={
      blur shadow={shadow blur steps=5,shadow xshift=1pt,shadow yshift=-1pt}}
      }

A resulting circuit with thin lines would render as this image:

When I try the same with quantikz2 (and TexLive 2024), the horizontal lines seem to disappear:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz2}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}

\begin{document}

\begin{quantikz}[thin lines, column sep=12pt, row sep=12pt, style={phase/.append style={scale=1.0}, operator/.append style={
      blur shadow={shadow blur steps=5,shadow xshift=1pt,shadow yshift=-1pt}}}]
  \lstick{\ket{q_0}} &\qw\slice{\ket{\psi_0}}& \gate{H} & \gate{R_2} & \gate{R_3} & \gate{R_4}\slice{\ket{\psi_1}}  & \qw      & \qw       & \qw\slice{\ket{\psi_2}}        & \qw      & \qw\slice{\ket{\psi_3}}      & \qw& \qw\\
  \lstick{\ket{q_1}} & \qw& \qw      & \ctrl{-1}  & \qw        & \qw        & \gate{H} & \gate{R_2} & \gate{R_3} &\qw       & \qw      & \qw& \qw\\
  \lstick{\ket{q_2}} & \qw& \qw      & \qw        & \ctrl{-2}  & \qw        & \qw      & \ctrl{-1} & \qw        & \gate{H} &\gate{R_2}& \qw& \qw\\
  \lstick{\ket{q_3}} & \qw& \qw      & \qw        & \qw        & \ctrl{-3}  & \qw      & \qw       & \ctrl{-2}  & \qw      & \ctrl{-1} & \gate{H} &\qw
\end{quantikz}
\end{document}


Any advice on how to correct this behavior? (Thanks)
with

welcome! can you complete the code snippets so we can compile them, please?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It is indeed a problem, but please extend your code example. It seems to be rooted in the shadows.blur library. With just drop shadow, this effect is not produced.

Thanks. I edited the question to make it more clear. Thanks Jasper - yes, drop shadow works but doesn't seem to be capable of the blur.

a workaround is to just load the old version, if you don't need v2 specific features?

Correct, cfr, that's exactly what I'm doing.

I would suggest to report the problem to the author (see the manual).

I’m voting to close this question because it is a bug report

I reported it to the author. Ok to close.
